# How will user reputation above 1000k be displayed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-interface

When the user reputation reaches 1000k, will it be shown as:

- 1000k?
- 1m?
- 1M?

Curiosity killed the cat! ;)

Comment: I hope it doesn't turn into 1/1000 rep points (as the `m` prefix would imply).

Comment: @Artefacto: What prefix?

Comment: `The Cat` isn't dead, it just changed its name to `Gnome`.

Comment: @GMan - The RTL prefix.

Comment: I would just let Jon Skeet worry about this.

Comment: @GMan The  `m` prefix means milli.

Comment: @Artefacto: I think you missed it: those are suffixes. :)

Comment: @GMan I see them as SI prefixes used in a standalone manner. 1k reputation == 1 krep

Comment: @Frankie - curiosity may have killed the cat, but satisfaction brought him back!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, that looks like it will take about another 8 years or so.  Calculate the number of 6-to-8 week periods in that time frame for the number of opportunities for the dev team to deal with that oncoming problem.

Thinking that SO is a static chunk of software that is always predictable is a very wrong mental image. They update it *daily*.  Very nice, I used to post to a forum site where updates were only permitted monthly.  They invariably broke basic functionality doing so and it would typically take a couple of *months* to get them to fix the bug.  Horrible.

MSDN forums btw.

Comment: yep... about 8-10 years to come. Nevertheless it's more of a curiosity issue than any other thing! ;)

Comment: Well, you can be sure that it won't look the same 8 years from now.  95% of all questions would be a duplicate by then.  You'll get rep from finding the dup.

Comment: It's theoricaly possible to have a reputation shown of 1 million in around 240 days. It's humanly impossible, but it's theoricaly possible. See my answer for details.

Comment: @Holy have you forgot about Jon Skeet? :)

Comment: It seems that your prediction will be quite accurate!

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest to introduce a new unit:

1000 k = 1 Skeet

Comment: and there will be noone other than him to get that unit :)

Answer (score 7):

The first place the 1 million reputation will be shown is on Area51 for the cumulative reputation of all the SE sites. Currently Jon Skeet is at [248k reputation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5220/board-and-card-games) for all the StackExchange sites.

If he was contributing to all the 21 StackExchange sites and reached the daily reputation cap everyday on all of them, in roughly 180 days he will be at 1 million reputation.

I think they have more than enough time to think about it.

Comment: Call it a hunch, but I don't think Skeet is planning to become a power player on the RPGs SE.

Comment: Actually, it's easier than that. If someone refers a bunch of high rep users to an area51 proposal, he/she can reach 1M in "total rep".

Comment: Jon Skeet is approaching 700K

Answer (score 4):

[Kyle](https://serverfault.com/users/2561/kyle-brandt) mentioned in chat that on a test instance he had given himself lots of rep.  If I understand what [he said](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/chats/message/84607?offset=-420) right now it will be displayed as 1000k

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a long way off, but sure it will be something reasonable like 1m as we currently have 1k.

[Jeff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) is still only at 85.5k so I doubt something like this will be coming soon.

Comment: but Jon Skeet is at 208k and rising at SO! ;)

Comment: @Frankie - maybe it will be 1sk?

Comment: hahaha! That sure is a nice one. Hope Jeff reads it.

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of killiviews we have

#### Rep

### Killah Rep

## MEGA REP

<sub>To be followed by Supah King-Kong Mega MEGA rep</sub>

As for how it should be displayed - remember how Super Mario Bros would just show symbols for the number of lives you had after doing the infinite 1-up trick?

Comment: Answering spree!  __Dominating!  SKEET-LIKE!!!__

Answer (score 0):

.001 G rep.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>** 1/1000 of 1000000000 rep. :)*</sub>